# How to trigger a "Command" binding inside a Property.Element syntax in Xamarin Forms UI Test

Tags: user-interface, testing, xamarin

I'm trying to do a Xamarin Forms UI Test. Currently I'm stuck with how to trigger a "Command" inside a Property.Element syntax via the app.Tap() method in Xamarin Forms UI Test.

Please refer to the link below.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/104352/how-to-trigger-a-command-binding-inside-a-property-element-syntax-in-xamarin-forms-ui-test/p1?new=1

Comment: Any reason you are using an EventToCommand behavior rather than just binding the Command directly?

Comment: @SteveChadbourne Thanks for your response. This was coded by a colleague, I'm just doing UI Test for it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
app.Tap(c=>c.Marked("btnProceed"))
```

Also, are you sure your data triggers are allowing your button to be enabled?

The best way to handle UI Testing long term is by using the Page Object Pattern

[Here is a good explanation](https://xamarinhelp.com/page-object-pattern-will-make-better-xamarin-ui-automation-tester/) on how to set it up.

Comment: Actually the button trigger must be triggered after entering a phone number via app.EnterText() (which is working) but when reaching the app.Tap("btnProceed") the test stops and doesn't trigger the associated logic behind it.

Comment: Added a link to details about the page object pattern.